# How to set data in model class?

Tags: java, android, arrays, json, model

I want to parse JSON and set the data. I have this model

```
public class Model {

    public List<Test>test;

    public class Test implements Serializable{
        String b;

        public Test(String a){
            this.b=a;
        }
        public String getId() {
            return a;
        }

        public void setId(String a) {
            this.a = a;
        }
    }
}
```

and from another class, I want to set data in class Test:

```
model.Test mm = new Model.Test("1");
```

but I got the error "isnot an closing class".

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that in java because `Test` is not `static`. To create a new instance of `Test` you need an instance of outer class, which is `Model`:

```
Model model = new Model();
Test test = model.new Test("1");
```

If you want to be able to create an instance without an instance of outer class, mark class `Test` as `static`. Then you will be able to use it this way:

```
Model.Test test = new Model.Test("1");
```